# Dynamic interface for array of object property value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have array of objects. Each object inside array represents an html input field. I want to load different interface on the base of `type` property inside the field.

```
interface Field {
  type: 'text' | 'radio';
  name: string;
}
interface TextField {
  placeholder: string;
}
interface RadioField {
  values: {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  }[];
}
const fields: Field[] = [
  {
    // How to make use of TextField interface here
    type: 'text',
    name: 'firstName',
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommand you to define the `Field` type by the union with `TextField` and `RadioField` that extends a `FieldCommon` interface. Like that you are more precise so that a radio field **should** have `values` for example:

```js
type Field = TextField | RadioField

interface FieldCommon {
  name: string;
}

interface TextField extends FieldCommon {
  type: 'text'
  placeholder: string;
}

interface RadioField extends FieldCommon {
  type: 'radio'
  values: {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  }[];
}

const fields: Field[] = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'firstName',
    placeholder:'Test' // valid
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'firstName', // error: Property 'placeholder' is missing
  }
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEygXigFQgD2PJVAHygCUBDZOAewJQCh64A7YCAJwDNyBjaO5AGFqAWxHVmUAN70oUZuREQAXFADOwdiwDmAbnoBfRizZde0bHgFRcbZsjWwEKYWInTZUUJFUByNni+nmCI5gAW1CgcqhpazHqGxqwc3HxklDTWthD2jgKu4pIyct4qUL7sGdRBcgBu5IgArhBqqsVyUPVNZbE6+h1QoQBGSDGafZ4GANoAuvpGPBIaUJzODqoCs+hQU57tJeBl-ra+ADSecgpKfqvsGgByihBnF1Ah4ZHI0b7YGjVQBnOcn2XkOfgCwBeAyuR1uDyeZygAHokTZ2OxqOxVAAFDGQdigcrvPgRKLsXxQOCOERUtQ6Sb0GZAA)

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad No problem :/ don't forget to `validate` the answer if it's answering the question ;)